# What is the use of super in implemented class?

Tags: java, inheritance, super

Following is the code I encountered during execution of Kinesis Streams

```
Class XYZ implements ABC {
       XYZ(){
        super();
     }
    }
```

What is the use of super in this case ?

Comment: Here ABC is an interface

Comment: There is no use here.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth it's implied if omitted. Maybe "redundant" is a better description

Comment: I also think so, then why java allowed to use super in constructors of implemented classes?

Answer (score 1):

`super` is used to invoke the `constructor`, `methods` and `attributes` of the parent class. In this case super will invoke the constructor of `Object` class, which by default in Java is super class of all classes. hence, `super` is redundant in this case.

Comment: I am not sure you are right. that is depend if the interface contains default implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The use of super() in the subclass means invoking the super class constructor. In case that the **Class XYZ** implements an interface, there is no meaning for the constructor invocation, cause the interface usually does not contain implementation.
I know that since Java 8 there is the ability to add default implementation to an interface. When the interface contains the **default** keyword before a method or a constructor that means default implementation for the related method or constructor.

You can read more about [Interface Method Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.5.6).

Comment: Does that mean interface can have methods which are implemented?

Comment: Yes, a default implementation. It does not break compatibility with pre-existing binaries.